# Load WFS in Leaflet with BBOX query in non-default projection (i.e. not EPSG:3857)

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, geojson, wfs, proj4js

I've had a look at this question: [How to add a bounding box filter to this leaflet WFS request?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/169129/78212) and have been trying to work out how to get it to work in a different projection system, specifically EPSG:2193 in this case.

My stack is currently SQL Server -> Geoserver -> WFS in Leaflet.

I have already done the following:

- Install the SQL Server [extension](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.9.1/user/data/database/sqlserver.html) and configured the layer in geoserver
- Enabled jsonp [Request JSONP from Geoserver using AJAX request in Openlayers 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/141414/78212)
- Loaded up the proj4leaflet plugin http://kartena.github.io/Proj4Leaflet/

So far, I'm aware that Leaflet can load WFS through a GeoJSON call. It is primarily the GeoJSON call I'm having trouble with I think. The javascript code (see below) passes the wfs GetFeature call alright, but Geoserver does not seem to listen to the BBOX parameter, or something along those lines. In other words, I can't get the right vector features to display because the WFS getFeature request only returns the top items from the database.

EDIT: I've changed some configurations in geoserver Data -> Layers -> Edit Layer so it might work now:

[image]

---

My skeleton html is currently as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>My first Leaflet Map</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 720px"></div>

    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./src/proj4.js"></script>
    <script src="./src/proj4leaflet.js"></script>
    <script>
      //insert javascript here
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

and the javascript part look something like this. Note that my WFS is deployed from localhost so the script technically won't work.

```
    //Set EPSG:2193 projection system here
    var nztm = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:2193',
       '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=173 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1600000 +y_0=10000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs', {
         resolutions: [
           8192, 4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128
         ],
       });

     // initialize the map on the "map" div with a given center and zoom
     var map = L.map('map', {
       center: [-43.80752, 172.94770, ],
       zoom: 15,
       //crs: nztm
     });

     L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
       maxZoom: 17,
       attribution: 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
     }).addTo(map);

     var start_at_zoom = 13;

     function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
       // does this feature have a property named OBJECTID?
       if (feature.properties && feature.properties.OBJECTID) {
         layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.OBJECTID);
       }
     }

     //Adds the GeoJSON layer to the map
     var featureLayer = new L.GeoJSON(
       null, {
         onEachFeature: onEachFeature
       }).addTo(map);
     load_wfs();

     //function to load geojson layer
     function loadGeoJson(data) {
       // console.log(data);
       $("#total").html(data.features.length);
       featureLayer.clearLayers();
       featureLayer.addData(data);
     }

     //when user stops dragging the map, (re)load the wfs layer
     map.on('moveend', load_wfs);

     //function to load the wfs layer
     function load_wfs() {
       if (map.getZoom() > start_at_zoom) {
         var geoJsonUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/test/ows';
         var defaultParameters = {
           service: 'WFS',
           version: '1.0.0',
           request: 'getFeature',
           typeName: 'test:PARCEL_LAYER',
           maxFeatures: 10,
           outputFormat: 'text/javascript',
           format_options: 'callback: getJson',
           srsName: 'EPSG:4326'
         };

         var customParams = {
           bbox: map.getBounds().toBBoxString()
         };
         var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters, customParams);
         console.log(geoJsonUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters));


         $.ajax({
           jsonp: false,
           url: geoJsonUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters),
           dataType: 'jsonp',
           jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
           success: loadGeoJson
         });

       } else {
         alert("please zoom in to see the polygons!");
         featureLayer.clearLayers();
       }
     }
```

The GeoJSON I get back does not adhere to the WFS BBOX parameter settings, I'm simply getting the top 10 features from the database.

---

Geoserver log below (may or may not make sense)

```
2016-08-29 08:25:55,346 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getFeature
    service = WFS
    version = 1.0.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    query[0]:
        filter = [  bbox POLYGON ((172.8623199462891 -43.83081186459637, 172.8623199462891 -43.78621481611623, 173.02428245544436 -43.78621481611623, 173.02428245544436 -43.83081186459637, 172.8623199462891 -43.83081186459637)) ]
        srsName = EPSG:4326
        typeName[0] = {www.test123.com}PARCEL_LAYER
    maxFeatures = 10
    outputFormat = text/javascript
    resultType = results
    formatOptions = {CALLBACK= getJson}
2016-08-29 08:25:55,346 INFO [wfs.json] - about to encode JSON
2016-08-29 08:26:02,438 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geometry": 
System.ArgumentException: 24144: This operation cannot be completed because the instance is not valid. Use MakeValid to convert the instance to a valid instance. Note that MakeValid may cause the points of a geometry instance to shift slightly.
System.ArgumentException:
```

I think my confusion lies in where to do the reprojection to EPSG:2193. Is it the leaflet map itself I have to reproject to EPSG:2193, or the WFS bbox call which I have to reproject to EPSG:2193 to get the features, and project the output GeoJSON to Leaflet's default EPSG:3857?

Comment: Can you add the xml request sent to geoserver?

Comment: Do you mean this? http://localhost:8080/geoserver/test/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=getFeature&typeName=test%3APARCEL_LAYER&maxFeatures=5&outputFormat=text%2Fjavascript&format_options=callback%3A%20getJson&srsName=EPSG%3A4326&bbox=172.85957336425784%2C-43.8307499473432%2C173.02153587341311%2C-43.78615285261544 I'll add something from the geoserver log too to the post.